# Is there an API to convert time in FILETIME format from UTC to local time?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I know that [SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API can convert from UTC time to local time, but it takes time in SYSTEMTIME format. I'm curious if there is an API that accepts FILETIME format instead?

PS. I know that I can achieve this by using FileTimeToSystemTime() and then SystemTimeToFileTime(). I was just trying to save two steps for converting to SYSTEMTIME and back.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`FileTimeToLocalFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724277.aspx)

> Converts a (UTC-based) file time to a local file time.

And [`LocalFileTimeToFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724490.aspx):

> Converts a local file time to a file time based on the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

However, you cannot convert between a UTC `FILETIME` and a local `FILETIME` in a specified timezone.  The current timezone of the local machine is used for the conversion.  The documentation states:

> To account for daylight saving time when converting a file time to a local time, use the following sequence of functions in place of using FileTimeToLocalFileTime:
>  
>   1. FileTimeToSystemTime 
>   2. SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime 
>   3. SystemTimeToFileTime

And

> LocalFileTimeToFileTime uses the current settings for the time zone and daylight saving time. Therefore, if it is daylight saving time, this function will take daylight saving time into account, even if the time you are converting is in standard time.

Comment: And the reverse?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably misunderstood something, but how can one convert to a `local time` and not "account for daylight saving"? What kind of a time would that be?

Comment: @MikeF: what that means is that if you write a file at 2pm, local time, on a Thursday, say, and then daylight savings starts that weekend, when you look at the file on Monday it will say that it was written at 1pm.  The system uses the *current* time zone, rather than the time zone that was in effect at the time you wrote the file.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Well but that is wrong. It should've said 2pm instead.

Comment: @Mike When does DST start 20 years from now?

Comment: @MikeF: that's a lot more difficult than you might think.  It was probably put in the too hard basket ages ago, when Windows had to be compact enough to run on systems with 256KB of RAM (that's kilobytes, not megabytes!) and no hard disk drive.  And since then, of course, backwards compatibility restraints made it impossible to change.